# what is list method in python?

Tags: python, django

I couldn't find any reference about `list()` on the python site.
Can you please provide a reference about it?

Example of some code in Django:

```
list(Tag.objects.filter(name__istartswith=q)[:10])
```

What does this mean?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list

Comment: `list()` converts a queryset to a python list.

Comment: ohh.. it in python site.. :p.. .Thanks @MartijnPieters :)

Comment: In all fairness, the person probably did have trouble finding a reference to the list() function, given that search engines do not play nicely with parentheses.

Comment: @akdev2 it is python basic list ie `[]` you have better to work on python first. if you are using linux, just type `python` in the terminal to enter the python console. now try basic python command. i recommend book [thinkpython](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkpython.pdf). +1 it is not nice fair such large number of downvotes to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`list()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#list) creates a Python list object.

Given an iterable, all elements of the iterable are copied over to the resulting list:

> Return a list whose items are the same and in the same order as *iterable*‘s items.

The expression `Tag.objects.filter(name__istartswith=q)[:10]` creates an iterable that results in 10 `Tag` objects, whose name starts with `q` (with a case insensitive match).

This simply creates a local copy of the query result, perhaps so the code can index directly into the list without re-issuing a new query each time.

This is specifically documented on the [Django `QuerySet()` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated):

> **`list()`**. Force evaluation of a `QuerySet` by calling `list()` on it. For example:
>
> ```
> entry_list = list(Entry.objects.all())
> ```
>
> Be warned, though, that this could have a large memory overhead, because Django will load each element of the list into memory. In contrast, iterating over a `QuerySet` will take advantage of your database to load data and instantiate objects only as you need them.